# How can I cast a child class to its parent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, casting

I have a Parent class and I have an extra attribute I want to temporarily store on that parent class. The Parent class is used outside of my code, and I don't want my added attribute used there.

What I *think* would be a good approach would be to create a child class, add my attribute there, and later on up-cast that child to the parent class, removing any attributes I was using in my code.

That approach does not seem "pythonic" - and there is no easy way to simply cast my child class back to the parent. So is there another way I can do this, or is there a way to cast this child class back to the parent?

I've put some psuedo code that might help you understand the issues:

- some Parent methods are being used in my codebase (so extending Parent seems appropriate)
- one attribute of the Parent can only be set right at the end using my custom_arg Child attribute
- one method on the Parent I think converts all attributes to a json - so I don't want any attributes I'm setting in the Child to end up there. I can delete Child attributes once I'm done with them, but that seems messy as it will still be of type "Child" but lacking Child attributes

So the cleanest solution I can think would be to make a clean copy of the Parent class, that does not have any of the Child class methods or attributes - but I haven't seen a good way to do that. I'm open to better suggestions too. In simple terms - I just need to add an attribute to this class while it is used in my codebase, and then remove that once I'm done.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg_needs_to_be_set, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg_needs_to_be_set = arg_needs_to_be_set
        self.arg3 = arg3
    def set_attribute1():
        ... does some stuff to set this attribute
    def to_json(self):
        return {... gets all attributes and puts them in attribute name: value form...}
    
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, custom_arg, arg1, arg2):
        self.custom_arg
        self.super(arg1, arg2, arg_needs_to_be_set=None)
```

Comment: Is there a reason your parent class should not have the child class attribute?

Comment: "What I think would be a good approach would be to create a child class, add my attribute there, and later on up-cast that child to the parent class, removing any attributes I was using in my code." What do you mean by "upcast"? This is *python*. It isn't a statically typed language, so the term "upcast" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the real problem is that `Child.to_json()` is returning `custom_arg` in the json object, when that is not desired.

This is not the problem you think it is, for two reasons.

1. if `isinstance(obj, Child) is True`, then `isinstance(obj, Parent) is True`, so if you pass an instance of `Child` to something expecting an instance of `Parent`, it will Just Work
2. in your child, you can **override** methods in the parent to give the behaviour you want, so you specialize `to_json()` to filter out `self.custom_arg` - any code anywhere that calls the to_json() method on an instance of `child` will get the expected result

So to do this a little more pythonically:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg_needs_to_be_set, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg_needs_to_be_set = arg_needs_to_be_set
        self.arg3 = arg3

    @property
    def attribute1(self):
        return self._attribute1

    @attribute1.setter
    def attribute1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._attribute1 = # whatever needs to be done, if it's funkier than just an expression

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps({k.lstrip("_"): v for k, v in vars(self).items()) # Or whatever else needs to be done

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, custom_arg, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1, None, arg2)
        self.custom_arg = custom_arg

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps({ k.lstrip("_"): v for k, v in vars(self).items() if k != "custom_arg"})
```

Clear as mud?